# AS3 browseForOpen opens last used folder

Tags: actionscript-3, air, filesystems

```
var f:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath('myFolder');
f.browseForOpen("foo");
```

running that code once will open the file opening dialog in the proper folder. But if i browse to another folder and select a file from there, and then later run the same code again, the file browsing dialog that opens will open in the folder from where i selected the last file, instead of 'myFolder'.

What's the reason for this and how to prevent this? (the browseForOpen dialog should always open in 'myFolder')

Comment: If you do what you actually showed here, it works fine for me. Are you doing something else in your code -- something like not creating a new File f each time browseForOpen is called?

Answer (score 0):

Agree - it appears to be a problem with AIR Runtime.

browseForOpen does not appear to allow preloading a directory.  For Example: cannot have multiple buttons that browseForOpen with each one targeting a different directory.  While this functionality works within Flash Professional development environment, it does not appear to work in a published AIR application.